# How can I detect USB serial port connections in C on Windows and macOS?

Tags: c, tty, libudev

Using libudev in Linux I am able to add a handle to an event manger to detect on boot and upon plugging in a USB serial device by monitoring tty events.

```
self->udev_monitor = udev_monitor_new_from_netlink(self->udev, "udev");
udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(self->udev_monitor, "tty", NULL);
udev_monitor_enable_receiving(self->udev_monitor);

self->event_manager->addFD(
    self->event_manager
    ,_udevDeviceAnnounce
    ,udev_monitor_get_fd(self->udev_monitor)
    ,self
);

_findUdevDevices(self);
```

How can I achieve the same thing on Windows and macOS? I am trying to make a single service written in C compiled for each Windows, Mac and Linux.